# javascript deep clone not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, deep-copy

I have a array like

```
const array = [
{name:'jack', age:12, sex:'male'}
{name:'mary', age:16, sex:'female'}
{name:'harry', age:22, sex:'male'}
]
```

so have do I deep clone another array out of it, I want to modify the second array that I clone from the original array without modify the original one.

I have tried `[...array]` or array.slice[0] even I tried `_.deepClone` from lodash, or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` somehow its all not working. I think they all work because the concept is if you change the original array, it will not modify the second one. but the scenario is reversed in my case, I want to change the second array without change the original one.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` has to work. There's no way the produced array is still referenced to the original one. Please show us this part of the code too, not only the array you are trying to clone.

Comment: Unclear how it would not be a copy with those methods. What is your actual test case. Show the code that does not work.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm fairly sure `secondArray` will still be a reference to `array`. Deep cloning wouldn't be such a difficult endeavour if it was that easy

Comment: @JeremyThille - holy cow - I totally misread the question! I think I got tripped up when I saw what you pointed out in your first  comment

Comment: `[...array.map(data => ({...data}))]`

Comment: it cannot work as your array is not valid, missing commas. const array = [
    {name:'jack', age:12, sex:'male'},
    {name:'mary', age:16, sex:'female'},
    {name:'harry', age:22, sex:'male'}
    ]